# clojure/ring/jetty: I am using > lein ring server. How do I configure the jetty instance that gets instantiated?

Tags: clojure, jetty, leiningen, ring

When I was calling the jetty handler directly, I was able to pass in a configurator like so:

```
(def header-buffer-size 8388608)
(defn start [port]
  (ring/run-jetty
   (var app)
   {:port port
    :join? false
    :host "127.0.0.1"
    :configurator
    (fn [jetty]
      (doseq [connector (.getConnectors jetty)]
        (.setHeaderBufferSize connector header-buffer-size)))}))
```

I had to do this because I kept getting a FULL HEAD error when posting.  Now I refactored things to use > lein ring server directly, which gets called from the command line.

```
> lein ring server
```

This uses some configuration specified in my project.clj:

```
:ring {:handler caribou.api.core/app
       :servlet-name "caribou-api"
       :init caribou.api.core/init
       :port 33443}
```

This works great, but now I am getting the FULL HEAD issue again.  So I tried to add a configurator in there:

```
:ring {:handler caribou.api.core/app
       :servlet-name "caribou-api"
       :init caribou.api.core/init
       :configurator
       (fn [jetty]
         (doseq [connector (.getConnectors jetty)]
           (.setHeaderBufferSize connector 8388608)))
       :port 33443})
```

And this fails with this stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
  at ring.adapter.jetty$run_jetty.invoke(jetty.clj:66)
  at ring.server.standalone$serve$fn__833.invoke(standalone.clj:78)
  at ring.server.standalone$try_port.invoke(standalone.clj:12)
  at ring.server.standalone$serve.doInvoke(standalone.clj:75)
  at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423)
  at ring.server.leiningen$serve.invoke(leiningen.clj:20)
```

I figured this had to do with putting the function directly in the map like that, so I defined it outside the project (in caribou.api.core) and tried referring to it like I do the rest of the functions defined elsewhere:

```
;; in caribou/api/core.clj
(def header-buffer-size 8388608)
(defn full-head-avoidance
  [jetty]
  (doseq [connector (.getConnectors jetty)]
    (.setHeaderBufferSize connector header-buffer-size)))

;; in project.clj
:ring {:handler caribou.api.core/app
       :servlet-name "caribou-api"
       :init caribou.api.core/init
       :configurator caribou.api.core/full-head-avoidance
       :port 33443})
```

This spins up the app, but I still get the 413: FULL HEAD error when posting.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stuff written inside a `defproject` form is not evaluated by default, but you can use `~` (unquote) in `defproject` when you need it to:

```
(defproject foo "1.2.3"
  ...
  :some-fn-key ~(fn [& args] ...))
```

In this particular situation, you'd unquote the `fn` form defining your configurator function (which without unquoting is being used as a list containing a bunch of symbols, rather than compiled into a function).

Alternatively, you can define the configurator outside the `defproject` form and refer to its name inside `defproject` as in your second approach, but then you need to unquote the name inside `defproject` -- otherwise it'll be treated as a symbol. NB. in the latter case no exception is produced, because symbols are in fact callable and accept arbitrary arguments (but only ever return `nil` when called with something other than a map or a set; with maps or sets, they look themselves up in their arguments).

Comment: That is probably something that changed since the answer was posted, but when I do like proposed here (unquote the function definition) I get another error: "No reader function for tag object". Do you have an idea why this might happen?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is not to use ring server and just start jetty directly with ring/ring-jetty-adapter.  That way I can still pass in the configurator, which BTW has changed to this:

```
(defn full-head-avoidance
  [jetty]
  (doseq [connector (.getConnectors jetty)]
    (.setRequestHeaderSize connector header-buffer-size)))
```