# lein-ring - cannot call configurator function on ring-jetty-adapter - "No reader function for tag object" error

Tags: clojure, leiningen, ring

Using `lein-ring` plugin, I attempt to pass a `configurator` function to the ring jetty adapter. The minimal `project.clj` which reproduces the problem, and which is inspired by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289617/clojure-ring-jetty-i-am-using-lein-ring-server-how-do-i-configure-the-jetty), is:

```
(defproject sample "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [ring/ring-defaults "0.1.2"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.9.7"]]
  :ring {:handler sample.handler/app
         :adapter {:configurator ~#(println (.getClass %))}}) ; whatever...
```

The problem with this, is that it fails with a following error:

```
$ lein ring server-headless
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No reader function for tag object, ...
...
```

Declaring a function with `fn` form or `defn` separately doesn't impact the outcome. Now I realize this is probably not related to `lein-ring` itself, but I only reproduced the problem on a `:configurator` (that is, for example, calling a function to set a project description works fine).

I would like to understand, why this is happening (and understand the error message itself first of all), and, in the end, how to actually pass a configurator function when using `lein-ring` plugin.

Comment: why use ~#(....) instead of just #(...)?

Comment: I understood from the other SO answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289617/clojure-ring-jetty-i-am-using-lein-ring-server-how-do-i-configure-the-jetty) that values under `defproject` are not evaluated, and they need to be unquoted for that. Simply put, if I leave `#(...)` - reader macro expands to `(fn ...)` list, but no evaluation happens, and I get a "PersistentList cannot be cast to IFn" error. So as far as I understand, when unquoted, the `(fn ...)` form should actually evaluate and the defined function is supposed to be the result associated with the `:configurator`

Comment: OK, now I understand. I would try your solution with a 'real' anonymous function rather than the short-hand version i.e. try ~(fn [x] (println (.getClass x))) and see if that works. My guess is that the environment where defproject is being parsed does not include the tag for the shorthand anonymous function definition

Comment: Yes, tried that. As mentioned, using `fn` or also declaring the function outside of the `defproject` with `defn` doesn't change anything - same error is raised.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. One thing you could try is add org.clojure/tools.reader to your dependencies. I don't think it will fix the problem, but it might provide additional error/debug info. My guess is that for some reason, the reader is not able to interpret a token/tag when parsing the input. However, it isn't clear what item is causing this, so additional backtrace info might help identify what it is the reader doesn't understand